# CPLEX OPL - Summing and storing elements

Tags: cplex, opl

I have a tuple that has two entries: SourceNodes and PowerConsumptionArray. I want to sum all corresponding power consumptions for each source node.

For example (see image attached), source node 2 appears twice in the tuple. The corresponding power consumption values for this node are 22 and 0. I would like to add 22 and 0 and store it in an array with an index 2 (because it's the total power consumption of node 2). Any hints on how it might be achieved in OPL?

Thanks in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCsyP.png)

Answer (score 0):

you could use slicing:

```
tuple t
 {
   int sourceNode;
   float power;
 }
 
 {t} s={<1,0>,<2,22>,<2,1>};
 
 {int} sourceNodes={i.sourceNode | i in s};
 
 float power[i in sourceNodes]=sum(j in s : j.sourceNode==i) j.power;
 
 execute
 {
   writeln(sourceNodes," ==> ",power);
 }
```

gives

```
{1 2} ==>  [0 23]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and it works like a charm! Are there any sources where I could learn more about slicing in CPLEX?

Comment: See https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/model-building-oplcplex-alex-fleischer/ and https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/

Comment: You re welcome.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers